# Tomcat 6 Heap Size - Is this correct?

Tags: java, tomcat6, redhat, heap-memory, catalina.out

I am running multiple tomcats on a Red Hat box and I would like to configure separate heap size for each of them (some instances use more memory).

Can I set the heap size min/max bt entering the following into the catalina.sh file:

CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx256m"

Do I need add 'export'? i.e. export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx256m"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Best practice is to put the setting of environment variables in a file named `setenv.sh`/`.bat` in the bin folder.

The `catalina.sh` script has logic to call into this script, if it exists.

The reason why this is recommended is because it makes setting of environment variables needed for your installation portable: you can easily copy `setenv.sh` to other Tomcat installations, you can upgrade Tomcat to a newer version (which might overwrite `catalina.sh`) but still have your existing `setenv.sh`.

An example on how to set the heap size inside `setenv.sh`:

```
export JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx784M`
```

Comment: Note that `CATALINA_OPTS` is a better place than `JAVA_OPTS`. The former is only used when actually starting the Tomcat instance. `JAVA_OPTS` is also used to start JVMs that only interact with Tomcat (for example the JVM instance that is used to send the shutdown-message to a running Tomcat instance). Those JVMs usually don't need so much memory.

Comment: Wow, great point Joachim - thanks for that. I'll have to go update all our scripts now :)

Comment: @mattb Do you mind updating your answer as well to fit with Joachim Sauer comment?

Answer (score 1):

If you add this to anything in the Tomcat installation, it will affect all instances run on that machine.

I think you want to set JAVA_OPTS separately, in separate scripts, which each then invoke Tomcat's startup script. The scripts can set different heap sizes. Yes, you need to export.