# Change the java heap size in Tomcat6 server

Tags: java, tomcat6

How can i change the java heap size in tomcat6 running as windows service?

Answer (score 2):

Hope [this (increase java heap size)](http://www.coderanch.com/t/87422/Tomcat/increase-java-heap-size) and [this (Tomcat 6 Heap Size)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144037/tomcat-6-heap-size-is-this-correct) helps.

[image: Figure How to configure memory for Tomcat 6]